# ASP.NET Load Balancer IP Detect

Tags: asp.net

I am currently, using the following code to detect IP address.

```
<code>
    IP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
</code>
```

This works when we do not have the load balancer but, it does not work in the cases load balancer is there.

I need to support both. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I am using the below mentioned code as in the above code, is not present in the context:-

```
IP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

//Not Behind the Load balancer or proxy server
   if (IP == null)
    {
      IP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The original request IP is override by load balancer IP as the load balancer is the machine that recive the request. Your web server recives the request from the balancer, not from the client browser.

Some Load Balancers put the original request IP in HTTPHeaders. You can read this httpheader from ASP.NET.

Anyway, you must read your load balancer documentation and check how load balancer send the client browser IP to the web server.

Once you know how get client IP from load balancer you can check for the value in code.

Ex:

```
function getClientIP{

    var IP = getClientIPfromLoadBalancer();

    If  (IP != null){return IP;}
    else {return getClientIPfromRequest();}
}

IP = getClientIP();
```

As I do not know how your load balancer works I can not be more explicit with the example code.

Comment: I have already read it from similar post in the forum. But can we not have some generic code for the same which will catch the IP address when load balencer exists or not.

Comment: Thanks, let me check if the load balancer passes the IP address or not.